# How to sum the values of a JQgrid footer row when the value is already in linked

Tags: jqgrid-php

I have this code that needs to be display the total sum of few columns, The JQgrid works fine in normal column value. But when that column value is linked, It shows Nan

```
grid.jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    datatype: "local",
    height: containerHeight,
    width: containerWidth,
    colNames:[
        //'Region/Purchaser Name',
        'Order No. / Invoice No.','PO No.','Ship To','Ship To Attention','Address','City','State / Zip','Requested Ship Date','Shipped Date','Total Qty Ordered','Shipped to WF','Open Qty'],
    colModel:[
        //{name:'REGION',index:'REGION', width:20},
        {name:'DUMMYMACNO',index:'MACNO', width:19, align:"center"},
        {name:'PONUM',index:'PONUM', width:17},
        {name:'SHIPTO',index:'SHIPTO', width:17},
        {name:'ATTN',index:'ATTN', width:19,align:"center",formatter:nullFormatter},
        {name:'ADDRESS',index:'ADDRESS', width:19},
        {name:'CITYJ1',index:'CITYJ1', width:10},
        {name:'STZIP',index:'STZIP', width:10},
        {name:'SDATE',index:'SDATE', width:10},
        {name:'INVDATE',index:'INVDATE', width:10},
        {name:'TQO',index:'TQO', width:4, align:"center"},
        {name:'DQTY',index:'DQTY', width:5, search:false, align:"center", sorttype:"float", formatter:function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){return '<a href="#qtyShippedModal" id="'+rowObject['MACNO']+'" class="getQtyShippedSummary" data-toggle="modal">'+cellvalue+'</a>';},classes: 'blue-text'},
        {name:'OQO',index:'OQO', width:6, search:false, align:"center", sorttype:"float", formatter:function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){return '<a href="#openQtyOrderedModal" id="'+rowObject['MACNO']+'" class="getOpenQtyOrderedSummary" data-toggle="modal">'+cellvalue+'</a>';}},

    ],
    rowNum:100,
    rowList : [100,150,200],
    loadonce:true,
    mtype: "GET",
    casesensitive: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    rownumWidth: 40,
    ignoreCase: true,
    gridview: true,
    pager: '#locationlistpagination',
    sortname: 'SONO',
    viewrecords: true,
    loadComplete: function() {
        $("tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass('jqgrow-alt-row');
    },
    sortorder: "asc",
    footerrow: true,
    gridComplete: function() {
        var colsum = 0;
        var colsum1 = 0;
        var colSum2 = 'Total';
        var colSum4 = 'Total';

        var colSum = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'DQTY', true, 'sum');
        var colSum4 = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'OQO', true, 'sum');
        var colSum1 = grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'TQO', false, 'sum');

        grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { OQO: colSum });
        grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { DQTY: colSum4 });
        grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { TQO: colSum1 });
        grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { SDATE : colSum2 });;
    }

})
```

The query works fine in ColSum1 and colSum2, but its shows Nan in ColSum and Colsum4. Can any one have a way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The getCol method sum a values which are numbers in grid, after they are formatted from the formatter. The values where you get NaN are not numbers, but links after formatting. In order this to work correctly you should define a unformat function which will convert back the link to a number. See the [Guriddo docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/formatters/#unformatting)